# Aplicar la misma clase a varios elementos ActionLink en MVC C#

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

Necesito aplicar una misma clase a muchos elementos ActionLink para darle estilos. De momento tengo este código:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Panel de Administrador", "Registro", "Registro", new { @class = "enlace" })
@Html.ActionLink("Cargar Casa", "Create", new {@class = "enlace" })
```

Pero al aplicar estilos solo me toma mi primer ActionLink.

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo solucione, por alguna razon  mi 2do ActionLink esperaba tener 4 parametros al igual que mi primero, de modo que el codigo ahora lo tengo asi:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Panel de Administrador", "Registro", "Registro", new { @class = "enlace" })
@Html.ActionLink("Cargar Casa", "Create", "Home", new {@class = "enlace" })
```

Y funciona perfectamente.